# Sed regex to add multiple spaces

Tags: sed

I'm looking for a clean way to add multiple spaces to a sed statement.  Having literal spaces in the statement works:

```
sed -i 's/this is a test/\n          and so is this/' test_file.txt
```

but I was hoping for a more precise way to accomplish this with regex.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _more precise_? Do you mean that you want to insert an arbitrary number of spaces by using that number?

Comment: Yes, so instead of 10 literal spaces, specifying the number "10"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash` or `zsh`, you can get an arbitrary number of spaces in a variable with:

```
printf -v spc %10s
sed -i "s/this is a test/&\n${spc}and so is this/" test_file.txt
```

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
sed -i "s/this is a test/&\n${(l:10:)}and so is this/" test_file.txt
```